# Mistake in my code and lucky answer

Tags: java

Spoiler alert!! for project euler problem 19.

The problem is how many sundays fall on the first of the month from 1901 to 2000. Given information: Jan 1st 1900 was a monday, Jan & march etc have 31 days, April, June etc 30 days and a leap year occurs on any year evenly divisible by 4, but not on a century unless it is divisible by 400. which in this case applies to year 2000.

I got the correct answer, but when I checked my results with a real calendar, it turns out my code is counting saturdays. I don't see why it is doing that, can someone help?!

```
public class Sunday {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int sundayCount = 0;
    int currentday = 0; // monday is 0, sunday will be 6
    int dayLimit = 0;

    for (int year = 1900; year < 2001; year++) {
        for (int month = 1; month < 13; month++) {
            // 30 days April, June, September, November
            if (month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11)
                dayLimit = 30;

            // leap year
            else if (month == 2 && year % 4 == 0)
                dayLimit = 29;

            // February not leap year
            else if (month == 2 && year % 4 != 0)
                dayLimit = 28;

            // Jan, March, May, July, August, October, December
            else
                dayLimit = 31;
            for (int day = 1; day <= dayLimit; day++) {
                if (day == 1 && currentday == 6 && year > 1900) {
                    System.out.println("year: " + year);
                    System.out.println("month: " + month);
                    sundayCount++;
                }
                if (currentday < 6)
                    currentday++;
                else
                    currentday = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sundayCount);
}
}
```

Comment: Aren't you forgetting that 1900 wasn't a leap year in the code?

Comment: In addition to the answer given by Asthor, have you taken into account the fact that Jan 1st 1900 was actually a Monday?

Comment: @GeorgeTomlinson January 1st 1900 was a Monday. http://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/?year=1900

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to add into the code to check for if febuary 1900 should have 29 or 28 days. As 1900 wasn't a leap year it shouldn't have 29 days in 1900.

```
else if (month == 2 && year % 4 == 0 && year != 1900)
    dayLimit = 29;

// February not leap year
else if (month == 2)
    dayLimit = 28;
```

This should fix it.

Comment: @GeorgeTomlinson The code already check if year % 4 == 0 in the first else if in cases where the month is 2. If that returns false then the second check which checks if the month is 2 should by default have year % 4 > 0. So the second check is redundant. It would actually require us to add yet another check for 1900 in the second else if.